# REST service with load balancing

Tags: rest, web-services, load-balancing

I've been considering the advantages of REST services, the whole statelessness and session affinity "stuff". What strikes me is that if you have multiple deployed versions of your service on a number of machines in your infrastructure, and they all act on a given resource, where is the state of that resource stored?

Would it make sense to have a single host in the infrastructre that utilises a distributed cache, and any state that is change inside a service, it simply fetches/puts to the cache? This would allow any number of deployed services for loading balancing reasons to all see the same state views of resources.

Comment: This seems highly theoretical, could you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Statelessness is not specific to REST. What do you mean about "session affinity"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're designing a system for high load (which usually implies high reliability), having a single point of failure is never a good idea. If the service providing the consistent view goes down, at best your performance decreases drastically as the database is queried for everything and at worst, your whole application stops working.

In your question, you seem to be worried about consistency. If there's something to be learned about [eBay's architecture](http://www.ddj.com/blog/architectblog/archives/2007/08/ad_2007_the_eba.html), it's that there is a [trade-off to be made between availability/redundancy/performance vs consistency](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/ebaybase). You may find 100% consistency is not required and you can get away with a little "chaos".

A distributed cache (like [memcache](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)) can be used as a backing for a [distributed hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) which have been used extensively to create scalable infrastructures. If implemented correctly, caches can be redundant and caches can join and leave the ring dynamically.

REST is also inherently cacheable as the HTTP layer can be cached with the appropriate use of headers ([ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)) and software (e.g. Squid proxy as a [Reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29#Reverse_proxy)). The one drawback of specifying caching through headers is that it relies on the client interpreting and respecting them.

However, to paraphrase Phil Karlton, [caching is hard](http://plasmasturm.org/log/542/). You really have to be selective about the data that you cache, when you cache it and how you invalidate that cache. Invalidating can be done in the following ways:

1. Through a timer based means (cache for 2 mins, then reload)
2. When an update comes in, invalidating all caches containing the relevant data.

I'm partial to the timer based approach as its simpler to implement and you can say with relative certainty how long stale data will live in the system (e.g. Company details will be updated in 2 hours, Stock prices will be updated in 10 seconds).

Finally, high load also depends on your use case and depending on the amount of transactions none of this may apply. A methodology (if you will) may be the following:

1. Make sure the system is functional without caching (Does it work)
2. Does it meet performance criteria (e.g. requests/sec, uptime goals)
3. Optimize the bottlenecks
4. Implement caching where required

After all, you may not have a performance problem in the first place and you may able to get away with a single database and a good back up strategy.

Answer (score 8):

I think the more traditional view of load balancing web applications is that you would have your REST service on multiple application servers and  they would retrieve resource data from single database server.

However, with the use of hypermedia, REST services can easily vertically partition the application so that some resources come from one service and some from another service on a different server.   This would allow you to scale to some extent, depending on your domain, without have a single data store.  Obviously with REST you would not be able to do transactional updates across these services, but there are definitely scenarios where this partitioning is valuable.

If you are looking at architectures that need to really scale then I would suggest looking at Greg Young's stuff on CQS Architecture ([video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/greg-young-unshackle-qcon08)) before attempting to tackle the problems of a distributed cache.